# What is a simple explanation to the fact that the universe is expanding?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion

How can we prove that the expansion of the universe is actually occurring to highschool children?

Comment: You can't "prove it" to physics Ph.D.s either and there is no simple explanation for "why" it is happening. There may be no explanation, at all. There are measurements that demonstrate that it is happening. You can show these measurements, i.e. a Hubble diagram like this: http://blog.mcnalu.net/lectures/starsanduniverse/images/my_hubble_numbers.gif, but to generate one of these, that takes advanced telescopes and full time astronomers. It's not high school stuff, I am afraid. A lot of other astronomy is, though, and that's what I would do with the kids, instead.

Comment: Are you asking why it's expanding as opposed to contracting?  Or why it's non-static as opposed to static?  If the latter, I think it is fair and accurate (though not a full story) to tell a high school student that out of all the possible rates of contraction and expansion, it would be a remarkable coincidence if the actual rate were exactly zero.  If the former, it might just come down to the fact that we *define* the forward direction of time to be the direction in which the universe is expanding, so there's nothing else to explain.

Comment: @WillO: The direction of time is set by local physical clocks. That the universe expands is an observation, not a definition. If we go back to e.g. "The First Three Minutes" by Weinberg, he was a strong supporter of an oscillating universe, I believe (I haven't touched my copy in like 30 years, so that's just my memory of his position). At the time his opinion seemed perfectly reasonable to me... a decade later, or so, was the dawn of precision astronomy and I think very few things have turned out to be as "wrong" as the oscillating universe.

Comment: @CuriousOne:  I'm not claiming to have thought hard about this, but it's quite unclear to me how the direction of time can be set by a local physical clock.  All I can tell from my clock is that if I define time as going in one direction, it registers t=1, then t=2, then t=3 ---- whereas if I define time as going in the opposite direction, it registers t=3, then t=2, then t=1.  If there's any actual difference between these directions (as opposed to just an arbitrary definition) then it seems to me that I need more than my clock to tell me what that difference is.

Comment: @WillO: By the hand of the clock always moving in the same direction. You never get the same reading twice, i.e. a physical clock counts 1, 2, 3, 4... and we never see 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 0... etc.. Not all systems do this, and the ones that don't are not qualified as clocks. That is a definition, of course, and one that has non-trivial consequences, e.g. we can ask if the fastest possible systems still have this property or if we can find such clocks in the early universe. For now it's empirically possible to find and make them, but that might very well be a "privilege" of the current era.

Comment: @CuriousOne:  Yes, I agree that it is an empirical fact that there are some things that count in one direction only, never backtracking, and that those are the things we define to be clocks.  I agree also that the existence of clocks has non-trivial consequences.  But it also seems to me that that if all you have is a clock, there is no way tell the difference between "this clock is moving forward through time" and "this clock is moving backward through time" unless you simply take the clock's direction as the *definition* of forward.

Comment: @WillO: We compare two or more clocks at different locations. This could still fool as about non-monotonous global time, of course, but it can't fool us about the possible non-monotonicity of local clocks/time. For good clocks that is not being observed (even though even good clocks have some really "dirty" behavior that shows up during that measurement!), but I do agree that one can not assume that this is the "normal" state of the universe. My statement is really restricted to physics as it appears now, not as it is, in general. I said this is not a high school topic, it's very complex.

Comment: @CuriousOne:  I do believe we're not communicating, which is perhaps inevitable given the limitations of these comment boxes.  I'm not arguing about non-monotonicity.  All I'm saying is that after we've all agreed that there is a monotonic global time coordinate, our choice to label one direction as "forward" and the other as "backward" appears to me to be pretty arbitrary.  And it also seems to me if you arbitrarily choose to label the direction in which the universe expands as "forward" then there is no mystery about why the universe expands in the direction you've labeled forward.

Comment: @WillO: You are losing me a little here. I don't think anybody seriously thinks that there is a global time in relativity. There is a reasonable global direction of the expansion of the universe when measured in the usual definition of the direction of past-future on local clocks. That's not semantics but a well defined orientation. We could distinguish it clearly from a collapse. The only question is what makes the universe expand NOW and will it possibly collapse back later. We don't know that, but the CURRENT measurements, in linear extrapolation, don't support that hypothesis.

Comment: @WillO *all* directional designations along a single dimension are arbitrary. That doesn't release us from the possibility of explaining *why* or *how* something happens in that dimension. You can take an explanation of "why does the train begin moving east when the engine turns the wheels counterclockwise," reverse all the directions, and the physics is still the same.

Comment: Instead of worrying about teaching our high school students such non-trivial concepts, I would rather worry about teaching them Introductory Physics based on a strong Mathematics background in a Universal and Systematic way across all 50 States. This way they won't face nightmare when taking introductory mechanics for their "Engineering" majors. Stereotyping is not ethical but I am worrying truly when I see that a first-year engineering student doesn't know how to solve for $k$ in $1/k=1/k1+1/k2$ or that $sin(x)\sim x$ only for small $x$ in radians rather than degrees.

Comment: If expansion cannot be proven or explained then what Reasons have been ruled out? I mean has it been disproven that something like time  is making it appear to be expanding?

Answer (score 1):

> What is a simple explanation to the fact that the universe is expanding?

Show them a [star map](http://pics-about-space.com/night-sky-map-planets?p=1) and point out the galaxies and the fact that it is a projection of three dimensional space to an image.

Astronomers and astrophysicists have spent a lot of effort measuring the behavior of the galaxies, their motions relative to each other and to the solar system, with complicated methods. They have found out that everything is moving away from each other.

How can that be?

Take a small balloon, and ask them to imagine it is even tinier. Stick with glue, while they watch you,  two or three   small pieces of paper on the surface, explaining that these are galaxies. Blow the balloon slowly making sure the galaxies do not fall off :). This will demonstrate how everything that is on the surface goes away from each other, in the two dimensional universe of the surface, for ants on it, for example.

Make them understand the extrapolation to three dimensions in which  the stars and galaxies are embedded ( same as the  pieces of paper)

> How can we prove that the expansion of the universe is actually occurring to highschool children?

We cannot prove it with anything else than the observations and measurements, which lead to making a model of an expanding universe, which describes the data.

Make sure that they understand the difference between a descriptive explanation and a theoretical one. For the balloon we know the theory. For the universe there exists a theory which is being continually tested with new observations and measurements, but expansion is the best model we have up to now.